# Get a specific template overloaded method pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, overloading

I have this class:

```
class A{
    template<typename Type = int32_t> Type b(){}
    template<typename Type = int32_t> Type b(Type a, Type b){}
}
```

And I would like to get a pointer for the function `b<int>()` and `b<int>(int, int)`

I tried this but it doesn't know which one to pick:

```
auto t = (void (A::*)(int,int))(&A::template b<int>);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want:

```
auto t = static_cast<int(A::*)(int, int)>(&A::b<int>);
```

Your code works after you fix a bunch of other mistakes.